# Can IP addresses be considered different if are the same but have different subnet masks?

Tags: ip, ip-routing

Hy there,

I was wondering if it is possible to have two different networks connected on one router who which have the same ip, and are differentiated by a subnet mask?

For example:

192.168.1.0/24
192.168.1.0/16

Are they considered different because their network prefix is different?

Does that mean that with the ip address 192.168.1.0 we can actually address.

192.168.1.0/31 -> 2 computers - 2 (for broadcast and network name)

+

192.168.1.0/30 -> 4 computers - 2

+

192.168.1.0/29 -> 8 computers - 2

+

...

Does it mean that we can uniquely define adresses for, what ever the number turns out to be, computers?

Comment: Great question, I think a lot people make this assumption and its good to have it answered here authoritatively.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it does not. The subnet mask is used exclusively for routing decisions (the routing algorithm needs a hint what hosts are local and what needs to be sent to a gateway), the addresses have to be unique in any case.

See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_forwarding_algorithm

But you *can* set the netmask arbitrarily to match your requirements on subnet size, of course.

There are also techniques (mainly [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation)) which would allow two networks with overlapping IP address spaces to communicate by remapping the overlapping address spaces to unique ones. In your example, with two separate networks A and B both including subnets of 192.168.1.0/24, the remote subnet 192.168.1.0/24 could be presented as a different, not yet used subnet - e.g. 10.0.1.0/24. The router would perform the necessary address translation operations forth and back to re-establish address uniqueness as visible by each of the networks A and B.